# Enable app store

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I'm trying to turn on the app store for a site but keep getting the message "Apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server tell them to enable apps"

I've looked everywhere in central admin and site features and everything looks like it should be enabled but still get this message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quick pointer, when you are filling out the question form you'll see suggestions for similar questions above yours. A lot of the time you will find your answers right there :)

Comment: did you setup the app domain and all configurations?